# Failed to resolve: com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.12.0

Tags: android, arcgis

My Project environment:

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1

Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7621141, built on August 8, 2021

Project:

```
 implementation 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.12.0'
```

Module:

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
    }

}
```

gradle-wrapper

```
#Mon Sep 27 14:27:21 CST 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

Error: Failed to resolve: com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **maven { url 'https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis' }** in allprojects node, not buildscript node. repositories node in buildscript is the repos for plugins dependencies, like **classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"**, not the repos for the dependenices in project modules build.gradle.

```
 allprojects {
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
         maven { url 'https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis' }
     }
 }
```

Comment: In the lastest Android Studio Fox,it remove allprojects,And I set it in `settings.gradle`